# data structures in java to make changes apply from one process to other synchronously

Tags: java

I am trying to make two methods generator and consumer to run synchronously.I have tried queue but unable to achieve.
I am using the below code

```
@Override
    protected List<ConfigIssue> init() {
        client = new RtmClientBuilder(endpoint, appkey)
                .setListener(new RtmClientAdapter() {

                })
                .build();
        SubscriptionAdapter listener = new SubscriptionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscriptionData(SubscriptionData data) {
                for (AnyJson json : data.getMessages()) {
                    queue.add(json);
                }
            }
        };
        client.createSubscription(channel, SubscriptionMode.SIMPLE, listener);
        client.start();
        return super.init();
    }


    @Override
    public String produce(String lastSourceOffset, int maxBatchSize, BatchMaker batchMaker) throws StageException {  
        long nextSourceOffset = 0;
        if (lastSourceOffset != null) {
            nextSourceOffset = Long.parseLong(lastSourceOffset);
        }
        if (messageQueue.size() != 0) {
            for (AnyJson json : queue) {
                Record record = getContext().createRecord("some-id::" + nextSourceOffset);
                Map<String, Field> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("fieldName", Field.create(json.toString()));
                record.set(Field.create(map));
                batchMaker.addRecord(record);
                ++nextSourceOffset;
                messageQueue.remove();
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(nextSourceOffset);
    }
```

I am trying to Sync both init method and produce method.Since init method start first and produce method start later they are not in sync.Can it be achieved by multi threading?How?

Comment: You need BlockingDeque and producer/consumer pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: @duffymo could you help me how to implement for my code.The flow of my code is first init method starts ,then produce and then destroy method is called.All these methods are implementations of an abstract class

Comment: No, I'm not going to write it for you.  Doesn't the link I provided show you how to do it?